How to test a function that does write!, by sending a Vec<u8> in with Box<dyn Write>
I'd like to have a function that either writes to stdout or to a Vec. This is for an interactive CLI I would like to write tests for.
This works:
// To stdout
write!(std::io::stdout(), "{}", "foox\n".to_string()).unwrap();

// To a Vec<u8>
let mut vec_buf = Vec::new();
write!(vec_buf, "{}", "foox".to_string()).unwrap();
print!("Via string: {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&vec_buf).unwrap());

But when I try something like this:
fn write_stuff(w: &mut Box<dyn Write>) {
    write!(w, "foo");
}

I can run it with stdout:
    let mut buf = Box::new(io::stdout()) as Box<dyn Write>;
    write_stuff(&mut buf);

I can run it with a Vec<u8>:
    let mut buf = Box::new(Vec::new()) as Box<dyn Write>;
    write_stuff(&mut buf);

But then, how can I assert the contents after the call?
print!("Via string: {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap());

Results in:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/pipeline.rs:96:56
   |
96 |         print!("Via string: {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap());
   |                                    ------------------- ^^^^ expected `&[u8]`, found `&Box<dyn Write>`
   |                                    |
   |                                    arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[u8]`
              found reference `&Box<dyn std::io::Write>`

If I try this:
    let mut buf = Box::new(Vec::new());
    write_stuff(&mut buf);

I get:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/pipeline.rs:96:21
   |
96 |         write_stuff(&mut buf);
   |         ----------- ^^^^^^^^ expected `&mut Box<dyn Write>`, found `&mut Box<Vec<_>>`
   |         |
   |         arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut Box<(dyn std::io::Write + 'static)>`
              found mutable reference `&mut Box<Vec<_>>`
   = help: `Vec<_>` implements `Write` so you could box the found value and coerce it to the trait object `Box<dyn Write>`, you will have to change the expected type as well
note: function defined here


Your function shouldn't take &mut Box<dyn Write> to begin with. Just take &mut dyn Write (or probably even better impl Write) and you can pass write_stuff(&mut vec) directly.

Getting rid of the Box worked, thanks :). impl Write also works.
